# gforthmi segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, forth, gforth

I'm using *Gforth* 0.7.0 on Linux.  Every time I try to run *gforthmi*, no matter what parameters I use, it chokes on *segmentation fault* like below:

```
[bahman@bleda ussa]$ gforthmi ussa.fi -m 4M ussa.fs
redefined block-offset  

Segmentation fault.
redefined block-offset  

Segmentation fault.
redefined th  
*OS command line*:-1: No such file or directory
comp-image >>>./temp-image.fi1<<< ./temp-image.fi2 ussa.fi bye
Backtrace:
$7FE2020FE850 throw 
$7FE202134408 slurp-file 
chmod: cannot access `ussa.fi': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `./temp-image.fi1': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `./temp-image.fi2': No such file or directory
```

I tried it on both a 32bit and a 64bit machine and the results were exactly the same.

What am I missing/doing wrong?  I'd appreciate any help/idea.  TIA,

--
Bahman

Comment: Do you think it is a proper place to ask this question?

Comment: What's wrong with SO?!  Anyway, I'm open to suggestions :-)

Comment: Visit superuser.com for such questions :)

Comment: Alright.  I posted my [question](http://superuser.com/questions/354318/gforthmi-segmentation-fault) out there too.  Though I thought it's more a matter of Forth programming experience than system administration; so the right places to me is here.

Comment: [Resolution](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gforth/2011-11/msg00002.html) (at Gforth/GNU mailing list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my own silly mistake.  I was `2DUP`ing on an empty stack.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, this will remove this question from the unanswered list.